# Mix data from MySQL in MongoDB query?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query in MongoDB, which selects the last 10 conversations a user has participated in. They are sorted based on the last message in a conversation. I have a way to paginate between the results using $gt in the match statement. For now, this is commented out.

I limited the number of members to 3 (using slice), because a group conversation can contain, for example, 30, 40, 50, ... members.

**The problem:** I have a MySQL database to store relational information. So I have a table `users` and a table `followers`, to show who is following each other. I want to include this information in a way into MongoDB, so I can find 3 members I am following, to show relevant profile pictures of known people. Let's say I have a conversation with 50 members, then I want to retrieve 3 people I follow (if any), so I see familiar profile pictures. Is this possible in a way, or is my wish not possible?

**query**

```
db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        foreignField: "c_ID",
        from: "messages",
        localField: "_id",
        as: "messages"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$messages"
    },
    {
      "$sort": {
        "messages.t": -1
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "lastMessage": {
          "$first": "$messages"
        },
        "allFields": {
          "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$allFields",
            {
              "lastMessage": "$lastMessage"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        messages: 0
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "members.uID": "1",
        //"lastMessage.t": { $gt: ISODate("2020-02-04 20:38:02.154Z") }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: { "lastMessage.t": 1 }
    },
    {
      $limit: 10
    },
    {
      $project: {
        members: {
          $slice: [ {
            $filter: {
              input : "$members", as : "member", cond : {
                $ne : ["$$member.uID" , "1"]
              }
            }
          }, 3 ]
        }
      }
    },
  ])
```

**conversations document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }
    ]
}
```

**messages document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35ee5f40713a43aeeeb1c5"),
    "c_ID" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "fromID" : "1",
    "msg" : "What's up?",
    "t" : 1580591922,
    "d" : {
        "4" : 1580592039
    },
    "r" : {
        "4" : 1580592339
    }
}
```

Comment: MongoDB cannot mix data with other SQL database (neither other database in the same server) within Aggregation framework. But you can implement manually "inner join" command separately

Comment: How would that inner join work exactly?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://medium.com/@hanjchen/mongo-weekly-combining-data-from-mysql-and-mongodb-in-node-js-6889360456b4)